# Visual Studio 2013 editor default font size?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, font-size

I want to set my VS 2013 editor font to 150%, and I want that size to be as default. So that any project I open, it could open with the same font size. How could it be possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Press Tools -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Show Settings for: Text Editor there ist the Font Size Property.

Note that: The settings for Font and Size are global for all text elements in all Visual Studio editors. According to [How to: Change Fonts and Colors in the Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165337.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

[Tools] -> [Options] -> [Environment] -> [Fonts and Colors]

THEN

Select  from "Show settings for:" drop-down list.

THEN

Change font size in "Size:" text field.

LEGEND:

[...] = Button/Click

"..." = Label

Comment: Not sure why this has 2 down votes, it works for me, whereas the accepted answer did not. I can find no "Environment" selection in the Tools menu. I am using VS2013 Update 5.. probably a discrepancy between different Update versions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this?

TOOLS -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors
when you select Text Editor (Under "Show settings for") the Display Item is called Preprocessor Keyword.

good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can chnage font and size by tools --> options --> environment --> font and color.

Detail with screenshot is mentonied [here](https://blossomprogramming.blogspot.in/2017/08/change-font-and-size-in-visual-studio.html)